# Printing with Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, printing, dpi

Using java swing, I want to print with accurate physical dimensions irrespective to user's printer and its resolution

e.g: i want to print exactly 5cm x 3cm rectangle on paper.

I don't know how to find the current dpi for selected printer (consider even select printer might have multiple configuration for dpi which user might change from print dialog box while printing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's printing API pretty much "assumes" 72dpi, even though it can print to printers with a much higher resolution then this.

This makes things much easier, as you simply don't need to care.

Essentially, you can convert cm to pixels by converting to dpi...

```
double cms = 5;
pixels = (cms * 0.393700787d) * 72
// 0.393700787d is the number of cms per inch ;)
```

Take a look at [How to design an image in java to be printed on a 300 dpi printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975595/how-to-design-an-image-in-java-to-be-printed-on-a-300-dpi-printer/18975822#18975822) for further details

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. 
Surprisingly I couldn't find any reference on "72dpi assumption" on official java documents.
after searching i found "If you attempt to print a swing componenet on a higher resolution device (like a 300 dpi laser printer) the 72 dpi offscreen image will be rednered on the device. the end result is that your 300 dpi or 600 dpi printer will carefully render a 72 dpi image. The extra resolution of the printer will be wasted" page 288, Java 2D graphics by Jonathan Knudsen

Comment: When it first came out, this was true, they've made a lot of headway with supporting higher resolutions, which is really, really nice, but I guess they didn't want to break everybodies print code, so they kept it so that the basic printing still acted like it's printing at 72dpi

Answer (score 0):

Printer understands length/paper size in points only using java API. 1 inch contains 72 points on paper. Hence you need to refer (inch * 72)